# Postfix does not issue AUTH command

Tags: 16.04, server, postfix

I try to send email from my server through Postfix, but I can't get it to work. I'm using an external SMTP server as relay host. This is the relevant part of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
relayhost = [mail.myISP.nl]:submission
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
debug_peer_list=mail.myISP.nl
debug_peer_level=5
```

I installed `libsasl2-2`, `libsasl2-modules` and `sasl2-bin`. In `/etc/postfix/sasl_password`, I entered valid credentials:

```
[mail.myISP.nl]:587     myuserid:mypassword
```

after which I ran the command to convert the text file to a `.db` file:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_password
```

and reloaded Postfix's configuration:

```
sudo systemctl reload postfix
```

However, no mail actually gets sent. I ran a TCP dump on the following command:

```
echo "This is a test" | mail -s "Testing" jos@myISP.nl
```

And the result was the following exchange with the remote server:

```
(S) srv17610.myISP.nl ESMTP Exim 4.86.2 Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:06:24 +0100
(C) EHLO hostname
(S) 250-srv17610.myISP.nl Hello my.canonical.name.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
(S) 250-SIZE 20971520
(S) 250-8BITMIME
(S) 250-PIPELINING
(S) 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
(S) 250-STARTTLS
(S) 250 HELP
(C) MAIL FROM:<jos@myISP.nl> SIZE=310
(C) RCPT TO:<jos@myISP.nl>
(C) DATA
(S) 250 OK
(S) 550 relay not permitted, authentication required
(S) 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
(S) 503-relay not permitted, authentication required
(S) 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
(C) RSET
(C) QUIT
(S) 250 Reset OK
(S) 221 srv17610.myISP.nl closing
```

With (C) being Postfix and (S) the remote server. You can see that it doesn't issue an AUTH command, doesn't offer credentials, and therefore the mail is rejected. The `/var/log/mail.log` simply says that mail has been sent. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks legit,
 but postfix requires it's smtp_sasl_password_maps file to actually be stored in a optimized way not clear text.

if you don't have such a file

running the command:

> postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_password

will generate a sasl_password.db

> service postfix reload

to apply changes

Comment: Thanks, but I did those, many times over. I should have mentioned that, and will edit the question accordingly.